# Eclipse dependency failure on Install of Salesforce IDE

Tags: eclipse, force-ide

I'm trying to install the salesforce IDE (Force IDE) on eclipse, and I get a dependency error that I don't know how to read. Can someone translate it for me, and tell me which piece I need to install? I've tried reading it several times and I can't figure it out... usually I'm not bad at doing this... must be getting old!

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Force.com IDE 38.0.0.201701101558 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 38.0.0.201701101558)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Forms 3.6.200.v20150506-2029 (org.eclipse.ui.forms 3.6.200.v20150506-2029)
    Eclipse Forms 3.5.200.v20120521-2329 (org.eclipse.ui.forms 3.5.200.v20120521-2329)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Force.com IDE 38.0.0.201701101558 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 38.0.0.201701101558)
    To: com.salesforce.ide.ui.editors [38.0.0.201701101558]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Force.com IDE Editors 38.0.0.201701101558 (com.salesforce.ide.ui.editors 38.0.0.201701101558)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.ui.forms 3.6.200
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.8.1.dist-A8F8_IVVG4WVSPmeRoJgU5j9DVVo8nAGcMPL9 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.1.dist-A8F8_IVVG4WVSPmeRoJgU5j9DVVo8nAGcMPL9)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.forms [3.5.200.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.8.1.dist-A8F8_IVVG4WVSPmeRoJgU5j9DVVo8nAGcMPL9]
```

I'm on Debian Linux, running Eclipse Version: 3.8.1, Build id: debbuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Force.com IDE based on Eclipse is not supported now. 
As an alternative, you can try out JetForcer, IDE for Salesforce development based on IntelliJ platform or VSCode extension.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that Eclipse is on version 4.7 on their website. I think my Eclipse version is hopelessly outdated!

I'll update it and try again.